# error CS1593 in netcore."Delegate ... Does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, faker

I'm trying to seed my database with Bogus and Faker when this error occurs:

```
error CS1593: Delegate 'Func<Faker, Address, short>' does not take 1 arguments
```

This is my code snippet and the error starts at the BuildingNumber method.

```
if (!context.Addresses.Any())
            {
                var faker = new Bogus.DataSets.Address();
                var addressSkeleton = new Faker<Resa.Models.Address>()
                .RuleFor(a => a.Street, f => faker.StreetAddress())
                .RuleFor(a => a.Number, f => faker.BuildingNumber())
                .RuleFor(a => a.Latitude, f => faker.Latitude())
                .RuleFor(a => a.Longitude, f => faker.Longitude())
                .FinishWith((f,a) => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Address created with Bogus: {0}!", a.Street);
                });
```

According to the documentation found at https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus there should be no parameter in the method.

Comment: Looks to me it wants a lambda expression in the form of `(f, a) => faker.BuildingNumber()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the source of the problem might be that your "Number" property is type of short and the "BuildingNumber" method returns string instead of short. I am not sure for this answer, just looked your code and Bogus then write down this answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I noticed, in my Address model I created a property "Number" wich is an Int16, buildingnumber returns a string. So now I need to figure out how to convert it to an int but casting doesn't seem to work.

Comment: May be you can write an extension method for faker class to return BuildingAddress as int16?